# RStudio running on 32 bit on a 64 bit OS with 64 bit R installation

Tags: r, rstudio

The following is the version info for R on my Windows 10 desktop:

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

When I run a script using R studio, it is running on 32 bit. I got this info from my Task Manager. In the Processes tab of my Task Manager the name of process is given as

```
RStudio(32 bit)(3)
```

How do I interpret this? Is this reducing the efficiency with which R is using my machines processing power? If yes, is there any way I can make it run using 64 bit registers?

Comment: Are you confusing R and RStudio?

Comment: Have a look the following URL: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RStudio (the front-end) is a 32bit application, but it understands how to speak with both 32-bit and 64-bit R sessions. The bitness of the RStudio front-end does not affect performance of the R backend.

If R's `sessionInfo()` reports that a 64-bit version of R is running, then 64-bit registers and all will be used.

Comment: Thank you Kevin Ushey. That helps.